# How to ask for permissions in an hybrid app (no AndroiManifest, only config.xml)?

Tags: android, permissions, hybrid-mobile-app

from android M or higher, now we must ask for android permission. but i dont know how to add android permission. when i test my app with phonegap desktop, everything is ok, because phonegap ask for location. but when i try to build it become apk from phonegap build, the geolocation is error. i think it because i dont have the permission from my app that i build. i check in my setting app, and thats right, my app dont have permission.

this is my code of [config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F658A.jpg)

please someone help me to find out how to asking android permission in hybrid app, Thankyou !

Answer (score 1):

You can use an already created plugin for dynamic permission in PhoneGap. Following is the link to a plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

If you do not want to use it, you can create your own plugin that will provide accessibility between javascript code and java code.

Comment: sorry for late reply, i alr use it, and my app still not asking for permission. i add code permission.hasPermission(list,callback,null) in addEvetListener for deviceready, am i wrong to put the code there ?